# i keep getting the error Cannot resolve symbol 'MutableInteger. and the same on the getvalue() or setValue()

Tags: java

```
public static int LongestBubble(int[] Arr, int n){

    //SHARED BY REFERENCE VARIABLE

    MutableInteger maxLength=new MutableInteger(0);// error on this line

    getLongestBubbleLength(Arr,n,0,-1,State.START,0,maxLength);

    if(maxLength.getValue()<3)// error on this line
        return 0;

        return maxLength.getValue();// error on this line
} // end of procedure LongestBubble()
```

Comment: are you importing the MutableInteger class? Or do you have a MutableInteger class in the same package?

Comment: what is the import mutable integer command as ive looked everywhere but cant seem to find a precise one

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html